# Select value from dropdown and click on search

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want they select value for the `dropdown` from  the `Ville` `option` and then click on `search` option  for each value but the problem is that they do not select value from `ville` these is pag link https://www.barreaunantes.fr/annuaire/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDQQC.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
url='https://www.barreaunantes.fr/annuaire/'
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)

select=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"select[id='ville-select']" )
options = select.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"option")

for option in options[1:]: 
        t=option.get_attribute("value")
        
d=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[type='submit']")
d=d.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element locator strategy selection isn't in proper way. The following code is working as expectation. You can increase or decrease the range of value selection yours own way.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service,options=options)
url = 'https://www.barreaunantes.fr/annuaire/'
driver.get(url)

for x in range(4):
    select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ville-select'))))
    select.select_by_index(x)
    time.sleep(2)
    
    click_on_search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[@value="Rechercher"])[1]')))

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", click_on_search_button)
```

Comment: when they move  to `index 2` they show these error  `value="Rechercher"> is not clickable at point (778, 40). Other element would receive the click: <ul id="menu-menu_principal" class="menu">...</ul>`

Comment: @ developer I've edited.